# Why does BufferedWriter write method produce different results?

Tags: java

I don't understand why these two implementations produce different results?

Method with expected results:

```
    private void writeToFile(WorkoutLog log){
        try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/exercise/textfile2.txt", true));

        out.write(log.name.toString() + ", " + log.type + ", " + log.duration + ", " + log.caloriesburned + "\n");
        out.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {  
        System.out.println("error writing record to text file " + e );
    }
}
```

**data file result**

jim, 1, 123, 246

mike, 3, 12, 24

jim, 4, 50, 100

joni, 5, 40, 80

Method with unexpected result:

```
    private void writeToFile2(WorkoutLog log){
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/exercise/textfile2.txt", true));

        out.write(log.name.toString());
        out.write(", ");
        out.write(log.type);
        out.write(",");
        out.write(log.duration);
        out.write(",");
        out.write(log.caloriesburned);
        out.write("\n");
        out.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {  
        System.out.println("error writing record to text file " + e );
    }
}
```

**data file result**

joe, , ,@

fred, ,{,ö

Why is breaking the out.write statements onto separate lines causing the output to produce odd results?  Each method is being passed an array reference with object that stores the result to write as string, short, short short data types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that `log.type`, `log.duration` and `log.caloriesburned` are `int` values, which means you're calling the [`BufferedWriter.write(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29) overload. That just writes a single character. I suspect you just need:

```
out.write(log.name.toString());
out.write(", ");
out.write(String.valueOf(log.type));
out.write(",");
out.write(String.valueOf(log.duration));
out.write(",");
out.write(String.valueOf(log.caloriesburned));
out.write("\n");
```

Note that you should close the writer in a `finally` block so that it gets closed even if there's an exception.

Comment: Aboslutely correct. As a matter of preference, I tend to prefer `Integer.toString()` because it is slightly more readable to me. Of course, that's completely off point for the question, so you still get my +1.

Comment: Jon, why does the first implementation, on a single line, work as expected without the String prefix?